# When are custom React Hooks called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've read through the [React custom hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and I'm a bit confused about how/when they're called.

- Are they called on every update to the calling function/component, like `useEffect`, that is, when there is component mount, a render, etc?
- The example they give seems to imply that the custom hook is called everytime a parameter changes -- their example is*

[image]

and they say

> If we pick a different friend and update the recipientID state
> variable, our useFriendStatus Hook will unsubscribe from the
> previously selected friend, and subscribe to the status of the newly
> selected one.

So this is sort of like (or exactly like) the parameters you pass in the array that is the second parameter of `useEffect`, that is, if any of the parameters you pass to your custom hook changes, then the hook is called again?

- Lastly, whatever state that exists within a hook disappears immediately upon its return, just like a normal function (which, of course, it is)?  I understand that whatever state is created inside the custom hook with `useState` is local to the calling component, thus local to the custom hook, but if you returned from the hook a `set` function created inside the hook, would it have anything to set? Would closure apply? (I'm not sure why you'd do this, but I'm just curious, since the point of effects seems to be offloading side effects, and I was wondering whether you could do that with custom hooks, if for some reason you chose to).

  ```
   function useKludge(something) {
     const [isSomething, setIsSomething] = useState(something);

     return setIsSomething;
   }
  ```

* (I've pasted an image because SO won't let me format the code correctly for some reason)

Comment: Hooks are Hooks, "custom" or not. Hooks are called every time the component is rendered. `useEffect` takes a function and an array of arguments, and although the `useEffect` itself gets called on every render (it doesn't have any special treatment), it will only call the function it was passed after checking whether its dependencies changed. It's just a "custom" Hook too.

Comment: @RossAllen -- So, then, with respect to my second question, since changing the 'friend' through the `Select` changes the state of the component (through `useState`), the hook is called again because there is a re-render due to the state being changed?

Comment: @Cerulean Think of custom hooks being used inside a Component as simply being there. So if the custom hook has a `useState` and a `useEffect`, it is the "same" as having them inside the component without the custom hook.

Comment: Based on the docs, it sounds like @Alvaro is right: "Custom Hooks are more of a convention than a feature. If a function’s name starts with ”use” and it calls other Hooks, we say it is a custom Hook. The useSomething naming convention is how our linter plugin is able to find bugs in the code using Hooks." --https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html. So I'd guess that the time when a custom hook gets called is determined by when the official React Hook(s) it contains gets called.